# Extracting functionality to a separated class file is not working

Tags: android

I'm a noobie in OOP and Android, I'm facing a little problem that is frustrating me so much.
I'm creating an app that uses permanent storage.
Initially I created the code that access the saved preferences all mixed into the MainActivity, that worked, then I wanted to move that code to a separated class file.
The problem is that for some reason it won't work in a separated class file and after trying and trying I found that I could create an inner class inside the MainActivity class and that way it works.
I believe that it is related to the fact that if I create it as an inner class I don't need to make the inner class to extend Activity (again).
When creating an external class for the permanent storage handling, I needed to extend Activity on that class and I think that is the problem but I'm not sure.
Can somebody please explain to me why this is happening and maybe suggest the correct approach?
following I'm including a code snippet that works, but my goal is being able to create the class PermanentStorageHelper in a separated class file.
Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static MainActivity _mainActivity;
private TextView textView1;

// OnCreate
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Persistent preferences
    PermanentStorageHelper ps = new PermanentStorageHelper();


    // UI Initialization
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    String uId = ps.getuId();
    UiHelper.displayOnTextView(this, R.id.textView1, uId);

}



// =============================================
// This is the class I'm talking about, I'm unable to move this to
// a separated class (.java) file.
// It seems to be related to the fact that, if making this a separated
// class file, I need to extend Activity again and that is what
// seems to be the problem
// =============================================
public class PermanentStorageHelper /*extends Activity*/{

    // CONSTANTS
    public static final String USERUNIQUEID="userUniqueID";             // Saved setting 1
    public static final String FILENAME="mtcPreferences";               // Filename for persisting storage file
    // Fields
    public SharedPreferences shp;                                       // SharedPreferences field (1)
    public String uId;


    public PermanentStorageHelper(){

        // Preferences initialization (2)
        shp = getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Read Preferences (3)
        uId = shp.getString(USERUNIQUEID, null);
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    public String getuId() {
        return uId;
    }
    public void setuId(String uId) {
        this.uId = uId;
    }

}
```

Comment: when you move the class to another file, do you write the line `extends activity` in it or not?

Comment: You should not manually instantiate a class which extends Activity (only the platform code knows how to do everything required for that correctly).  The provided answers point out how to make your code work without having your helper class improperly extend Activity itself.

Answer (score 2):

pass a context to your new class:

```
    public PermanentStorageHelper(Context context){

    // Preferences initialization (2)
    shp = context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

}
```

Then you can create your class like:

```
new PermanentStorageHelper(MainActivity.this)
```

Comment: Hi, should I still extend Activity in the new class? @maclir

Comment: Thank you all guys, it works with your suggested approach, but I still need to extend Activity in the new class in order for it to work, if not, I get a compile-time error

Comment: No, don't extend Activity. What's your new error? It's likely a different issue.

Comment: Hi Leo, I tried not extending Activity but it won't compile my class PermanentStorageHelper. It will show the squiggly line at **shp = context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);** the squiggly line is on the constant MODE_PRIVATE hinting: _MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved as a variable_. But as soon as I add **extends Activity** to the head of the class the compile error goes away and the class works.

Comment: OK, change MODE_PRIVATE to Context.MODE_PRIVATE or to 0.[See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE)

Answer (score 0):

for `getSharedPreferences` you need to have access to the `activity` or `applicationContext`

You can add context to your constructor and use it to call `getSharedPreferences`:

```
 public PermanentStorageHelper(Context context){

        // Preferences initialization (2)
        shp = context.getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Read Preferences (3)
        uId = shp.getString(USERUNIQUEID, null);
 }
```

in which case you would need to pass it on when creating the instance of the object:

```
PermanentStorageHelper ps = new PermanentStorageHelper(getApplicationContext());
```

or

```
PermanentStorageHelper ps = new PermanentStorageHelper(MainActivity.this);
```